# How to remove encryption from volume during installation

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, encryption, raid, lvm

I'm currently in the process of installing Ubuntu Server 12.04 onto a fresh build. I have two 3TB hard drives that I'd like to run in software RAID 1, and was following [this tutorial](http://www.itfromscratch.com/install-ubuntu-server-12-04-with-encrypted-lvm-on-raid1/). During installation, I forgot that I had data on one of the hard drives (the other is new) and, in an effort to erase that data, did a stupid thing during the "Partition disks" section of the setup by choosing "Guided - use entire disk and set up encrypted LVM". Now one of the disks is encrypted and I can't seem to figure out how to reverse this action (if that's even possible). Or if that isn't possible, can someone advise me on how I should proceed at this stage?